# Android:pathpattern for intercepting file download intents from browser

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, download-manager

I`m trying to make something like downloadmanager and i got trouble with intent-filters.
My intent filter for catching file download intents is like this:

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
     <data android:scheme="http" />
     <data android:scheme="https" />
     <data android:scheme="ftp" />
     <data android:scheme="file" />
     <data android:scheme="data" />
     <data android:scheme="info" />
     <data android:scheme="data" />
     <data android:scheme="smb" />
     <data android:scheme="nfs" />
     <data android:scheme="content" />
     <data android:host="*" />
     <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.avi" />
     <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.mp4" />
     ....
 </intent-filter>
```

is there any way to make pathpattern look like * . * and match any filetype?

Comment: The scheme="data" line is in there twice.

Have you tried `<data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*" />` ?

Comment: @Buurman damn, you`re right. It worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've added it as a proper answer. Could you accept it so other people know this question's been answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scheme="data" line is in there twice.

Have you tried `<data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*" />` ?

Be aware that you will accept *any* type of file which might not be what you really want for a lot of reasons. But any ways, that is it.